# TFS2015: Code hub - build status

Tags: tfs-2015

In the web portal of TFS (2015.2) if I click on the Explorer tab I get the content of the source control; the main window has displayed at the top the source control path ($/fooProject/barFolder1) and a status indicator. The project is set to TFVC.

In my fooProject that status is showing the outcome of a build that happened 6hrs ago even meanwhile other builds had been executed. All builds are gated check-in builds set to be triggered on different folders.

Even if I browse to different folders the indicator is showing the result of the same build. Isn't supposed to show the result of the build that is triggered by changes on that folder?

Where can I find the documentation on that part of the TFS web portal?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of how to achieve this setting "All builds are gated check-in builds set to be triggered on different folders." for test?

Comment: Build1 has the Filters property of the Triggers tab set to $/fooProject/barFolder1.

Build2 has the Filters property of the Triggers tab set to $/fooProject/barFolder2 and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The build status only point to the build definitions which include the entire repository path like "$/fooProject". It does not show the status base on the folder you select.